# spring - inject property to a pojo class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, properties-file

How would you inject a value from a .properties file to a pojo class?
What I want to achieve is everytime I get an instance of this class, it will return to me an instance with that value already injected to it.  I put it in a .properties file instead of within the java class itself for I'll be needing it for easy change on configuration later.

I'm currently trying adding this annotation `@Value("${myfield.name}")` on my variable on my pojo class to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work:

```
@Value("${myfield.name}")
```

But you would need to annotate your class with any of `@Component, @Service` etc.
And you would need the property-placeholder tag on your xml ofcourse.

Comment: I am trying to inject the properties file fields in my pojo class it is always giving me null when I tried the same in the controller and services it works fine. could you please let me know what I need to do ?